# Building the Selenium Server Project

Tags: selenium

I need to apply a few patches to the Selenium CaptureNetworkTrafficCommand.java code.

In order to test the fixes, I will need to rebuild the selenium-server.jar.

Is there any easy way to build the selenium server if I'm only changing this file?

I've try both maven and rake and both seems to fail building.

Answer (score 1):

Since Selenium 1 is part of the new Selenium 2 code to keep backwards compatibility you need to follow the Selenium 2 [build process](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver).

To build the server do

```
go selenium-server-standalone
```

and to build Selenium jars do

```
go selenium
```