# Build selenium-server-standalone executable jar

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I did a patch in the HtmlUnitDriver.java file, as explained here:
[Is it possible to ignore JavaScript exceptions when working with WebDriver (HtmlUnit, Ruby bindings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745061/is-it-possible-to-ignore-javascript-exceptions-when-working-with-webdriver-html)

I've followed the explanations on the selenium build wiki and in the readme, also the tip given here:
[Building the Selenium Server Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306248/building-the-selenium-server-project)

Still, I don't have a jar file like selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar which can be run and used as a headless browser for selenium tests.

... So I'm trying to recreate the selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.jar file with my patch, and use it to run my headless tests.

Can anyone explain to me how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way I found is to do:

`go //java/server/src/org/openqa/selenium/remote/server:server:uber //java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium:client-combined:uber`

This will create a single jar for the selenium server

Then run `go release`.

The resulting .jar should be found in build\dist folder of the selenium source folder. (ex. `./build/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/selenium/selenium-standalone.jar`)

See also https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Building-WebDriver#tips.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step building guide for selenium standalone server. The build process of selenium projects may be not so strait forward to newbies, so I recommend this detailed guide on how to create a runnable standalone jar.

http://shengwangi.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-build-selenium-from-source.html

Also you can refer to the official document on build selenium. 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/BuildingWebDriver#Building_Selenium_Server

Comment: Besides links, please add relevant parts to your answer.